# Insert Keyword in Decision Table

Tags: insert, drools

I am new to Drools, and going through an existing use case where the action contains the `insert($param)` or `insert(new Object($param))`, i could not find the functionality of this keyword and the scope of this and how this is getting utilized further conditions.

Any response or documentation on this would help. I could not find this on any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read the official documentation here: https://docs.drools.org/8.32.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/rule-engine/index.html

The conditions of the rules in Drools are applied to "Facts" present in a `KieSession`. These "Facts" are nothing but Java objects. If you want to make an object a "Fact" then you have to **insert** it into the `KieSession`. Otherwise Drools will not know about its presence and no rules will be applied to it.

So, for example, if you have the following rule in your `KieSession`:

```
rule "Adult Person"
    Person(age >= 18)
then
    //do something
end
```

The `Person` pattern is making reference to a Java class named "Person". In Java, if you want to make a `Person` instance available to the `KieSession` you will need to do something like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(33); // up to this point, Drools is not aware of this object

kieSession.insert(person); //here we are telling Drools that the `person` object is a Fact and that the rules have to be evaluated for it.
```

In you case, the `insert` function is being called as part of the action of you rules and not straight from Java, but the idea is the same.